# Issues getting Git working with VSCode and files on web host

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

Until now I have always used FileZilla for transferring my local files to my host for changing a site Im working on. I want to change that and learn how to git gud! So basically the ideal situation would be to be able to work in VSCode on a directory which is mirrored from my web host and from there be able to make changes locally and then commit and change files on my web host when I want to - this has to be possible right?

I have been able to use Git Bash to connect to my host and files using ssh. I have created both an init --bare and init since Im not sure which one to use, but I do have the .git folder created there. I can also using the Bash and the command `git status` see all the files waiting for to be committed (?).

As I understand I have to initialize the repository, then commit them to "track" these files and have them visible in VSCode to work with, is this right?

But when I try to `git commit` following error message is displayed.

```
 Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found.
```

This points to that the relative pathing to vscode and/or git is not working, but it is. When I start-up the bash I can use for example `code --help` and `git config --global -e` to launch a window of VSCode. So my `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` is probably working as it should.

Although AFTER I have connected to my web host using ssh, neither of these command work anymore. Why is this?

And also, am Im on the right way right now in thinking on how to make this "connection" between VSCode, git and my web host (one.com)?

Im thinking that I have to create a local repository in the folder where I today have a duplicate of my web host-files and a remote repository at the actual web host and then make some kind of connection between them two and VSCode. Im not quite sure how yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be a little confused with what Git is and how you should be using it for what you want to do. Let's clear some stuff up.

Simply put, Git is a version control system for tracking changes to files over time. You create or edit your files, `git add` them to a "staging area" and then `git commit` them with a commit message. If you edit the files after committing them, then git can detect changes to the files and you can add and commit them again, or discard them depending on what you want. However the most important part to understand is that these changes are **local** at this point. If you want to share them with anyone (or have another system pull them down), then you will need to establish a remote repository.

This is what Github/GitLab are for. Log in/create an account on either site (gitLab provides free private repos) and create a repository named appropriately. Then once you have created a remote repo, follow the instructions to add it as a "remote" to your local repo, then `git push` your changes up to that remote one. Now, on your server, you will `git clone` the remote repo and that will pull down your changes. From then on, if you push new changes to the remote repo, you can pull the changes down to the server by doing `git pull`. This is a very basic and barebones approach to deploying code on the server and there are more sophisticated ways of doing it but I will keep it simple in this answer.

Git is completely separate from VSCode (although VSCode has some git integration and plugins). I would **not** recommend changing the `core.editor` to VSCode. What that setting controls is the editor that is used to author commit messages. Loading up VSCode takes too long for that...I recommend that you stick with the default Vim or use nano. Or, in most cases, specify a message when committing: `git commit -m "added foobar"`.

So, the git repo that is on your server (the one that you init'd with `--bare`) is junk and should be instead created by `git clone`ing from a remote repo. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: I see! And yes, Im very confused and have been the latest days.

So if I understand you correctly I should have: 
- a local repo which is init'd by git init
- a remote repository for example github or azuredevops (which I already pushed to) and push the local repo to
- then from server, firstly clone the github/azure repo first time and then pulling later changes.

One question is - the server cant also be my remote repo? I have to use this in a 3-way solution?

Also I already have the same files on server as locally. Should I delete these before cloning or does it overwrite anyway?

Comment: In theory, any computer can act as the remote repo, but if you have it on github/azuredevops, there are more benefits: secure, redundant backups, etc. I would not recommend making the same server that you serve the content on being your remote repo. Too much risk and you'd have to configure security etc. Not worth the hassle.

Comment: The 3-way solution might seem annoying but it's the most robust way in your current configuration. Like I said in the post, it is barebones. If you are using azuredevops, you might be able to configure a pipeline that auto publishes/deploys to your server, but that is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: I don't know what kind of server you are running but you should be able to clone the repo into another folder, delete the current one (or rename it just in case), then move/rename the cloned repo into the old one's spot and you should be good to go

Comment: Hopefully this is a good starting point for you. Once you have things working in the barebones way, my suggestion would be to begin looking into Continuous Deployment (CD). It all boils down to the type of application you are deploying of course. If it's simple HTML or PHP scripts, then the CD process should be rather simple. If you are deploying real apps in Java/C#/etc, the the process gets a bit more complicated. Good luck!